# How to display mathematical equations dynamically in iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, quartz-2d, equation

I have used Quartz2D for drawing mathematical equation for iPod/iPhone and below is the sample code.

Question :
In my app I have to show lots of these equations dynamically. *Do I need to read the **data to draw** and its **x / y coordinates** dynamically from a plist (or some other storage) and then draw the equation ?* Right now I am just hardcoding the data and x / y coordinates (*as seen in the sample code below* - ).

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
// Left hand side Starts --
float xaxis = 3.0f;

// Before bracket
NSString *textString = @"L";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 50.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Oblique" size:20]];

// Opening bracket
xaxis += 12.0f;
textString = @"(";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 30.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:50]];

textString = @"N";
xaxis += 12.0f;
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 50.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Oblique" size:20]];

// Numerator part
unichar oneChar[] = {0x2206};
xaxis += 31.0f;
textString = getTextString(oneChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 37.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:22]];

unichar twoChar[] = {0x03C9};
xaxis += 15.0f;
textString = getTextString(twoChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 38.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

xaxis += 15.0f;
textString = @"k";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 48.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];

// Line
CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();    
CGContextSetLineWidth(myContext, 2);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(myContext, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);    
CGContextMoveToPoint(myContext, 45, 65);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(myContext, 110, 65);
CGContextStrokePath(myContext);

// Denominator part
xaxis -= 40.0f;
unichar threeChar[] = {0x03C9};
textString = getTextString(threeChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 64.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

xaxis += 15.0f;
textString = @"res";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 74.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];

xaxis += 18.0f;
unichar fourChar[] = {0x0028};
textString = getTextString(fourChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 64.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

xaxis += 5.0f;
unichar fiveChar[] = {0x03B8};
textString = getTextString(fiveChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 64.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Oblique" size:20]];

xaxis += 15.0f;
textString = @")";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 64.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

// Closing bracket
xaxis += 8.0f;
textString = @")";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 30.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:50]];

// Equal to sign
xaxis += 15.0f;
unichar sixChar[] = {0x003D};
textString = getTextString(sixChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 50.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

// Right hand side Starts --

// Numerator part
xaxis += 15.0f;
textString = @"sin";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 42.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17]];

xaxis += 20.0f;
textString = @"2";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 38.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];

// Inner opening bracket
xaxis += 10.0f;
textString = @"(";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 37.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:22]];

xaxis += 8.0f;
textString = @"N";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 38.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Oblique" size:20]];

xaxis += 18.0f;
unichar sevenChar[] = {0x03C0};
textString = getTextString(sevenChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 40.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17]];

xaxis += 12.0f;
unichar eightChar[] = {0x2206};
textString = getTextString(eightChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 36.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:21]];

xaxis += 15.0f;
unichar nineChar[] = {0x03C9};
textString = getTextString(nineChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 38.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

xaxis += 15.0f;
textString = @"k";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 47.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];

xaxis += 8.0f;
textString = @"/";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 38.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:24]];

xaxis += 8.0f;
unichar tenChar[] = {0x03C9};
textString = getTextString(tenChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 38.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

xaxis += 15.0f;
textString = @"res";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 48.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];

xaxis += 18.0f;
textString = @"(";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 38.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

xaxis += 5.0f;
unichar elevenChar[] = {0x03B8};
textString = getTextString(elevenChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 38.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Oblique" size:20]];

xaxis += 12.0f;
textString = @")";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 38.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

// Inner closing bracket
xaxis += 6.0f;
textString = @")";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 37.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:22]];

// Line    
CGContextSetLineWidth(myContext, 2);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(myContext, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);    
CGContextMoveToPoint(myContext, 138, 65);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(myContext, 318, 65);
CGContextStrokePath(myContext);

// Denominator part
xaxis -= 175.0f;    
textString = @"N";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 65.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Oblique" size:20]];

xaxis += 18.0f;
textString = @"2";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 63.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];

xaxis += 8.0f;
textString = @"sin";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 68.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17]];

xaxis += 20.0f;
textString = @"2";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 63.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];

// Inner opening bracket
xaxis += 10.0f;
textString = @"(";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 64.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:22]];

xaxis += 8.0f;
unichar twelveChar[] = {0x03C0};
textString = getTextString(twelveChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 68.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17]];

xaxis += 12.0f;
unichar thirteenChar[] = {0x2206};
textString = getTextString(thirteenChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 65.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:21]];

xaxis += 15.0f;
unichar fourteenChar[] = {0x03C9};
textString = getTextString(fourteenChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 67.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

xaxis += 15.0f;
textString = @"k";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 75.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];

xaxis += 8.0f;
textString = @"/";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 64.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:24]];

xaxis += 8.0f;
unichar fifteenChar[] = {0x03C9};
textString = getTextString(fifteenChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 67.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

xaxis += 15.0f;
textString = @"res";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 75.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];

xaxis += 18.0f;
textString = @"(";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 66.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

xaxis += 5.0f;
unichar sixteenChar[] = {0x03B8};
textString = getTextString(sixteenChar, 1);
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 66.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Oblique" size:20]];

xaxis += 12.0f;
textString = @")";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 66.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];

// Inner closing bracket
xaxis += 6.0f;
textString = @")";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 64.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:22]];

// Extra text for information
xaxis = 6.0f;
textString = @"Above is the example of an equation drawn using";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 120.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14]];
xaxis = 6.0f;
textString = @"Quartz2D";
[textString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xaxis, 140.) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14]];

}

static NSString *getTextString(unichar chars[], int charLength)
{   
NSString *uniString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:chars length: charLength];
return uniString;
}
```

Comment: I was searching to find other ways of rendering mathematical equations in iPod/iPhone as well - and found that we can use MathML in UIWebView to display it just fine. So what is the difference between using Quartz2D (above procedure that I used) and MathML in UIWebView.

Comment: Anyone - can please reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well the difference is that you have much less control over a web view than you do what you do natively. With a web view you are wrapping a solution that someone else has come up with. If you do things yourself, you have much more control.

Answer (score 0):

If you're drawing a limited class of functions, e.g. polynomials, you could write up a routine that draws an arbitrary polynomial as a sequence of tiny connected line segments.

e.g.

```
#define STEP = .05f;
draw_polynomial(context, MIN_X, MAX_X, polynomial) {
    CGFloat y = polynomial.evaluateAtX(MIN_X);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, MIN_X, y);
    for (CGFloat x = MIN_X + STEP; x < MAX_X; x += STEP){
       y = polynomial.evaluateAtX(x)
       CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x, y);
    }
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
 }
```